# MongoDB: Command not found

Tags: macos, mongodb, terminal

I'm beating my head against a wall trying to install MongoDB on this Mac running OS X. I've tried both through brew and through the direct file download. Mongo is on my path, but I'm getting the error of "command not found" when running "mongo -version". I've created the /data/db directory and added the correct permissions, and my .bash_profile has the path specifications. What could possibly going on?

Answer (score 0):

You need put your mongodb directory in

> `/usr/local/`

After you go to change the  url in your ~/.bash_profile

Comment: it was - but I actually resolved the issue by reinstalling it for the 5th time through brew. But thank you!

Comment: It's pretty crazy how incomplete the install instructions are on the mongodb website. To install it you really need a good tutorial or browse stackoverflow for every little step.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was resolved by re-installing MongoDB once again, this time through brew, and it worked! Not sure what happened, still, but at least it's working.